# Polymorphic recursion - syntax and uses?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I've spent significant time looking over learnyouahaskell and I haven't found a good explanation of polymorphic recursion!

I understand basic recursive structures:

```
myFunction :: [Int] -> [Int]
myFunction [] = []
myFunction (x : xs) = (\x -> x + 1) x : myFunction xs
```

What would polymorphic recursion look like? And what are its benefits/uses?

Comment: If it's Haskell, why are you tagging C++?

Comment: [Practical Type Inference for Polymorphic Recursion: an Implementation in Haskell](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~camarao/sblp2003.pdf) provides some good examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type inference for polymorphic recursion is undecidable, meaning the compiler cannot *infer* the type of such a function even when it is well-typed.

For example, an ordinary list applies `List` to the same (polymorphic) type on both sides:

```
data List a = Cons a (List a)
```

while this type taken from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphic_recursion) applies `Nested` to two different (polymorphic) types, `a` and `[a]`:

```
data Nested a = a :<: (Nested [a]) | Epsilon
```

From the same article, the compiler will fail to infer the type of a relatively straightforward `length` function

```
length Epsilon = 0
length (a :<: xs) = 1 + length xs
```

because `length` is applied to values of two different types in the second equation, `Nested a` and `Nested [a]`.

The solution is to assert that the type is indeed `Nested a -> Int`.

```
length :: Nested a -> Int
length Epsilon = 0
length (a :<: xs) = 1 + length xs
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the 'Nested' example in a bit more simple terms? I've looked over the Wiki article and still a little lost, what does ':<:' do for example?

Comment: It's just an infix data constructor (which is like an infix operator, but must begin with `:`). You could write the same definition as `data Nested a = NestedCons a (Nested [a]) | Epsilon`, replacing the infix constructor `:<:` with a "regular" data constructor named `NestedCons`.

Comment: Could you give a brief example of their use? :P

Comment: @BabraCunningham It works just like `(:)` for lists. For instance, `['b', 'c']` is syntax sugar for `'b' : 'c' : []`, a `[Char]` built using the constructors `(:)` and `[]`. Analogously, `'a' :<: ['b', 'c'] :<: Epsilon` is a `Nested Char` built with the constructors `(:<:)` and `Epsilon`.

Comment: As I see it, your solution is exactly the same as the straightforward length function. I don't see how you "solved" the problem.

Comment: @Peter The solution is the explicit type annotation. With `:`, `(x:xs)` and `xs` have the same type. The same is not true with `(x :<: xs)` and `xs`; `(x :<: xs)` has type `Nested a`, while `xs` has type `Nested [a]`.

Comment: @chepner To make this answer more precise, I would put "...meaning the compiler cannot *always* infer the type..." Undecidability means that the we cannot solve a problem for every single instance, but we might come up with a solution that can spit out a correct answer in some cases.