# Applications of polymorphic recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, polymorphism

One limitation of implementing polymorphism in a language via monomorphisation (and monomorphisation only) is that you lose the ability to support polymorphic recursion (e.g. see rust-lang [#4287](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/4287#issuecomment-11846582)).

What are some compelling use cases for supporting polymorphic recursion in a programming language? I have been trying to find libraries/concepts which use this and so far I've come across one example:

1. In "The Naming Problem" where we'd like to have both (a) fast capture avoiding substitution and (b) fast alpha equivalence checking, there is the [bound](https://www.stackage.org/lts-11.15/package/bound-2.0.1) library (more detailed explanation [here](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/bound)). Both of these properties are desirable when writing a compiler for a functional programming language.

To prevent the question from being overly broad, I'm looking for other programs/libraries/research papers that present applications of polymorphic recursion to traditional computer science problems such as those involved in writing compilers.

Examples of things that I'm not looking for:

1. Answers showing how you can encode X from category theory using polymorphic recursion, unless they demonstrate how encoding X can be beneficial for solving Y which falls under the criterion above.
2. Small toy examples which show that you can do X with polymorphic recursion but you can't without it.

Comment: Note: This question is a more focused sub-question of the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40247339/2682729).

Comment: You need polymorphic recursion to operate on [`Seq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html) values.

Comment: @Carl, that's a good example. Could you expand that into a more full-fledged answer (e.g. what operations use polymorphic recursion/what additional benefits it provides compared to an implementation in another language without it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s one example close to my work that I think generalises fairly well: in a concatenative language, that is, a language built on composing functions that operate on a shared program state such as a stack, all functions are polymorphic with respect to the part of the stack they don’t touch, all recursion is polymorphic recursion, and moreover all higher-order functions are also higher-rank. For instance, the type of `map` in such a language might be:

> ∀αβσ. σ × List α × (∀τ. τ × α → τ × β) → σ × List β

Where × is a left-associative product type with a stack-kinded type on the left and a value-kinded type on the right, σ and τ are stack-kinded type variables, and α and β are value-kinded type variables. `map` can be called on any program state σ as long as it has a List of αs and a function from αs to βs on top, like:

```
"ignored" [ 1 2 3 ] { succ show } map
=
"ignored" [ "2" "3" "4" ]
```

There’s polymorphic recursion here because `map` calls itself recursively on different instantiations of σ (i.e., different types of “rest of the stack”):

```
-- σ = Bottom × String
"ignored"           [ 1 2 3 ] { succ show } map
"ignored" 1 succ show [ 2 3 ] { succ show } map cons

-- σ = Bottom × String × String
"ignored" "2"           [ 2 3 ] { succ show } map cons
"ignored" "2" 2 succ show [ 3 ] { succ show } map cons cons

-- σ = Bottom × String × String × String
"ignored" "2" "3"           [ 3 ] { succ show } map cons cons
"ignored" "2" "3" 3 succ show [ ] { succ show } map cons cons cons

-- σ = Bottom × String × String × String × String
"ignored" "2" "3" "4" [ ] { succ show } map cons cons cons
"ignored" "2" "3" "4" [ ] cons cons cons
"ignored" "2" "3" [ "4" ] cons cons
"ignored" "2" [ "3" "4" ] cons
"ignored" [ "2" "3" "4" ]
```

And the functional argument of `map` needs to be higher-rank because it’s called on different stack types as well (different instantiations of τ).

In order to do this without polymorphic recursion, you would need an additional stack or local variables in which to place the intermediate results of `map` to get them “out of the way” so that all recursive calls take place on the same type of stack. This has implications for how functional languages can be compiled to e.g. typed combinator machines: with polymorphic recursion you can preserve safety while keeping the virtual machine simple.

The general form of this is that you have a recursive function which is polymorphic over *part* of a data structure, such as the initial elements of an `HList` or a subset of a polymorphic record.

And as @chi has already mentioned, the main instance where you need polymorphic recursion at the function level in Haskell is when you have polymorphic recursion at the *type* level, such as:

```
data Nest a = Nest a (Nest [a]) | Nil

example = Nest 1 $ Nest [1, 2] $ Nest [[1, 2], [3, 4]] Nil
```

A recursive function over such a type is always polymorphically recursive, since the type parameter changes with each recursive call.

Haskell requires type signatures for such functions, but apart from the types, mechanically there’s no difference between recursion and polymorphic recursion. You can write a polymorphic fixed-point operator if you have a secondary `newtype` that hides the polymorphism:

```
newtype Forall f = Abstract { instantiate :: forall a. f a }

fix' :: forall f. ((forall a. f a) -> (forall a. f a)) -> (forall a. f a)
fix' f = instantiate (fix (\x -> Abstract (f (instantiate x))))
```

Without all the wrapping & unwrapping ceremony, this is the same as `fix' f = fix f`.

This is also the reason that polymorphic recursion doesn’t need to result in a blowup of instantiations of a function—even if the function is specialised in its value-kinded type parameters, it’s “fully polymorphic” in the recursive parameter, so it doesn’t manipulate it *at all*, and thus only needs a single compiled representation.

Comment: +1, I hadn't seen the Kitten example before. This one is particularly compelling in that it allows you to have both polymorphism + static typing in a whole language, not just have one fancy data structure.

Comment: @theindigamer: Thanks. :) I’m not sure what you mean by “not just one fancy data structure”, though. Also I wasn’t *exactly* using Kitten syntax for this post, just some type theory notation and concatenative pseudocode, but it’s similar enough.

Comment: By "one fancy data structure", I mean that sure, you can make types which are recursive in non-trivial ways, it isn't necessarily clear where such types should be used. The language example demonstrates a concrete use case.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes you want encode some constraints in types, so that they are enforced at compile time.

For instance, a complete binary tree can be defined as

```
data CTree a = Tree a | Dup (CTree (a,a))

example :: CTree Int
example = Dup . Dup . Tree $ ((1,2),(3,4))
```

The type will prevent non complete trees like `((1,2),3)` to be stored inside, enforcing the invariant.

Okasaki's book shows many of such examples.

If one then wants to operate on such trees, polymorphic recursion is needed. 
Writing a function which computes the height of a tree, sums all the numbers in a `CTree Int`, or a generic map or fold requires polymorphic recursion.

Now, it is not terribly frequent to need/want such polymorphically recursive types. Still, they are nice to have.

In my personal opinion, monomorphisation is a bit unsatisfactory not only because it prevents polymorphic recursion, but because it requires to compile the polymorphic code once for every type it is used at. In Haskell or Java, using `Maybe Int, Maybe String, Maybe Bool` does not cause the `Maybe`-related functions to be compiled thrice and appear thrice in the final object code. In C++, this happens, bloating the object code. It is true, though, that in C++ this allows more efficient specializations to be used (e.g. `std::vector<bool>` can be implemented with a bitvector). This further enables C++'s SFINAE, etc. Still, I think I prefer it when the polymorphic code is compiled once, and type checked once -- after which it is guaranteed to be type safe a all types.

Comment: It might be worth note that other GHC features are enabled by using polymorphic representation.  RankNTypes are particularly powerful and require a uniform in-memory representation of values in order to be polymorphic at runtime.

Comment: Funny that you should mention `std::vector<bool>`, which the C++ community generally considers a historical `fail`... But, quite generally speaking, monomorphisation does lead to better cache performance. In C++ you can stuff anything in a `vector` and be confident it will be efficient in memory. In Haskell, carrying around the `Unbox` or `Storable` constraint can be a bit of a burden by comparison.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Why is `std::vector<bool>` considered a failure? I'm not familiar with the downsides. I see the point about cache performance, but monomorphization sometimes repeats the same code over and over in the object file. OTOH, keeping only one copy of the code requires a uniform representation and an extra indirection which prevents some low-level optimizations. (Fortunately, in GHC we have `SPECIALIZE` to get something similar)

Comment: @chi `std::vector<bool>` breaks all kinds of assumptions C++ programmers like to make about vectors, such as being able to pass `v.data()` as a pointer to a C function that expects a plain old array. Also, it's in practice often actually _slower_ than a naïve implementation would be, since extra masks/shifts are required. — You're right about code bloat, but in many applications that's a worthwhile tradeoff. For small functions, the repetition doesn't matter much, and large ones are often only ever used with a few different types. – FWIW, Haskell isn't a champion of tiny executables either...

Comment: Hi, while this is a nice example, I'd consider it to fall under "Small toy examples which show that you can do X" ... I'm looking for a more fleshed-out examples where the additional power is helpful in solving some "practical problem". In my comment to the question, I've linked to another SO post which is also gives a small example and points to Okasaki's book -- I'm explicitly looking for medium to large scale examples here.

Comment: "[...] type checked once." IIUC, monomorphisation doesn't necessarily entail that you need to type-check multiple times unless you have a duck-typed template system like C++.

Answer (score 4):

I can share a real example I was using in my project.

Long story short, I have a data structure `TypeRepMap` where I store types as the keys and this type matches the type of the corresponding value.

For benchmarking my library I needed to make a list of 1000 types to check how fast `lookup` in this data structure works. And here comes the polymorphic recursion.

To do so I introduced the following data types as type-level natural numbers:

```
data Z
data S a
```

Using these data types I was able to implement the function which builds `TypeRepMap` of the desired size.

```
buildBigMap :: forall a . Typeable a 
            => Int 
            -> Proxy a 
            -> TypeRepMap 
            -> TypeRepMap
buildBigMap 1 x = insert x
buildBigMap n x = insert x . buildBigMap (n - 1) (Proxy @(S a))
```

so when I run `buildBigMap` with size `n` and `Proxy a` then it calls itself recursively with `n - 1` and `Proxy (S a)` at each step, so the types are growing on each step.

Comment: I'm curious though: what would you use a `TypeRepMap` for?

Comment: It was needed for another library that allows mutually recursive late-bound
 capabilities with runtime dispatch and a type-safe interface.